# Case insensitive Charfield in django models

Tags: django-models, case-insensitive

I am trying to achieve a category model where name has `unique=True`,
but practically I can still add same category name with different cases.

i.e. I have a category called Food
I am still able to add food, FOOD, fOod, FOOd

Is their any philosophy behind this? or it is a work in progress.

Cause in real world if I think of Category Food, it will always be food, no matter what case it has used to mention itself.

Thank you in advance to look at this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I have found I can have clean method on my model. So I added

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def clean(self):
        self.name = self.name.capitalize()
        return super().clean()
```

It is capitalising the first letter, which is then handled by the `save` method, which calls the `validate_unique` method to raise error.

Comment: 2017: Works very well!

Comment: 2021: doest work

Comment: @Aseem u  need to add 
        return super().clean()

Answer (score 3):

You can use Postgre specific model field called [Citext fields (case insensitive fields)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#citext-fields).

There are three option at the moment:

`class CICharField(**options)`, `class CIEmailField(**options)` and  `class CITextField(**options)`

Example:

```py
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.postgres.fields import CICharField


class Category(models.Model):
    name = CICharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255)
```

But don't forget to create an extension for the citext fields.
[See here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#create-postgresql-extensions)

Basically, you have to add the extension class in the migration file, inside the `operations` array, before the first `CreateModel` operation.

```py
# migration file

    operations = [
        CITextExtension(),        # <------ here
        migrations.CreateModel(
            ...
        ),
        ...,
    ]
```

Comment: "don't forget to create an extension for the citext fields. See here." link is broken

Answer (score -2):

Setting the column to case-insensitive collation should fix this. You may need to do it at the SQL level.

Comment: You mean setting column to "case-sensitive"? The question is how to do this in Django.

Comment: I think this is a better approach. Clean is not being called on the save method