# Is there a model.ICharField() in Django, for a case insensitive CharField?

Tags: django, django-models

There doesn't seem to exist a case independent `model.CharField()` in Django? That makes case independent unique values and list look-ups somewhat difficult.

For example, I am trying to do a `Model.objects.filter(field__in=[large-str-list])` lookup, with all the str values being randomly uppercase and lowercase. There is a 5-year-old [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360800/is-there-any-way-to-do-a-case-insensitive-in-query-in-django).

Also, ensuring case independent unique-ness of a `model.CharField()` can't be done by Django. There is another 5-year-old [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857822/unique-model-field-in-django-and-case-sensitivity-postgres) for that.

I was wondering if there is already a better solution now, maybe in the form of a model.ICharField() that can take care of off these things.

Comment: is it possible to save and query only values casted to `.lower()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486811/case-insensitive-charfield-in-django-models This might answer your second question.

Comment: the case stored in the database is part of the data and must be kept. A workaround would be to add a second "lookup" field and lowercase that. But I was hoping for a way without any such hacks...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to create your own field. It should not be too hard to check for uniqueness during insertions. As far as I know there is not a native Django solution for that. The old links in your post might help you.